# Unable to open a document using DocumentApp.openById() in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-docs

**I am trying to create a copy of a template document and edit some text in it using the following code :**

```
 const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId) //folder where to save the document 
 const copy = templateDoc.makeCopy(customDocName.toString(), destinationFolder); //make a copy of the template document
 const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()) //open the copy 
 const body = doc.getBody();
 
 //update the template with data
 body.replaceText('<text1>', 'replacementText');
 body.replaceText('<text2>', 'replacementText');
```

I am able to create a copy of the document, rename it and save it in the specified folder . I am getting the following error at line 3 : **Exception: The document is inaccessible. Please try again later.**

I have looked for the solutions and have tried all but nothing worked.

**Here is all that I have tried :**

- Logout and login again
- Enabled all relevant api under resources
- Moved the app script under a GCP project as someone suggested that we no longer can access a doc directly from app script.
- Enabled all relevant api's in GCP

Comment: Sometime this kind of error is temporarily. If not: Make sure that the file is a Google Docs file. Also: where is the folder located? On your Drive? Shared Drive? Shared with you? Which kind of permissions do you have over the folder?

Comment: How are you defining templateDoc?

Comment: @ziganotschka The folder is in my drive and I am the owner.

Comment: @sebbagoe templateDoc is a google doc that is present in the same folder as my script container. I am able to make a copy of template doc and save it in the specified folder. But when i try to open it using documentApp.openById() I get the mentioned error

Comment: The problem might also be related to being signed in with multiple accounts - please try out to sing out of all accounts but one before running the code or use incognito mode.

Comment: So you are getting it similar to destinationFolder? Like const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFolderById(...)?

Comment: @sebbagoe Thank you for your question on templateDoc. I think I have the solution now. The issue is that the templateDoc is a word document(.docx) . I created a google doc and tested the same thing. I was able to edit the copied document. Hope it will not fail again .

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the templateDoc as it was a **Microsoft Word Document(.docx)**. When i created a **Google Doc** and referred it as the template doc it worked just fine.
Thank you for all your help :)